# After upgrading to Kubuntu 12.10, machine boots directly to Memtest86

Tags: boot, upgrade, kubuntu

I have upgraded a virtual machine running Kubuntu 12.04 to 12.10. After the upgrade completed, I can no longer boot into the OS. After POST, I see three "error: file not found." lines, and Memtest86+ starts up.

I can only assume that the upgrade deleted all kernel images where the installed bootloader looked for them. Luckily this was in a VM and I saved a snapshot before beginning the upgrade, however I would still need to know how to prevent the distribution upgrade from breaking the system again.

Edit: My [/boot/grub/grub.cfg](http://dump.thecybershadow.net/739e640ca42ef4db5a192a888b920672/00000268.txt) before the upgrade.

Comment: Do you have access to your Grub still ?

Comment: No menu pops up. Is there a Grub equivalent to mashing the F8 key to get the Windows boot menu?

Comment: Nope, then we have your problem. You have grub missing, that is locating the images for your OS's and makes the computer load them. Without, yeah, it becomes a mess. I'll suggest you to open a new question where you ask for help to recover the GRUB menu. (Sorry, i am not experienced about those things). Good luck!

Comment: holding shift should stop the grub from auto-booing and fore it to show itself. you can then examine each entry and edit and boot if necessary.

Comment: Yep, figured that out by myself (see my answer below). However, Grub eliminated all entries except Memtest from the menu. I had to type the commands manually (again, see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GRUB menu timeout has been set to 0 (not a very good idea), which is why you never see the menu. However, you can hold Shift during booting to force the menu to appear.

I managed the boot the system by typing the following commands at the grub command line:

```
search --fs-uuid --set=root d6a0fd5a-96fb-4615-bf65-71904e36f947
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-31-generic root=UUID=d6a0fd5a-96fb-4615-bf65-71904e36f947 ro
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-31-generic
boot
```

The partition UUIDs are from the grub.cfg in the question.

After booting, I ran [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), which fixed the problem.